# How can I use a CAMediaTimingFunction to map a custom value?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, timing

I'd like to use a CAMediaTimingFunction (e.g. kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn) to map an input value (0-1) to an output value (0-1), just like [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) say this class does. However, this functionaity doesn't appear to be exposed at all.

Is there some way I can access this functionality for my own custom values? This is not in a UIView, CALayer etc - it's just in some custom code where I'd like to use the iOS curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19084008/251440

I needed it myself so built a class with the interface and capabilities exactly like `CAMediaTimingFunction` but with the needed `-valueForX:` method.

Comment: Great stuff. I ended up doing something very similar after reading the Webkit source. Wish they'd just put this in the iOS API, would have saved a lot of duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that functionality is the only functionality that is exposed. A CAMediaTimingFunction is a class that stores the coordinates of the two control points that define a Bézier curve that begins at (0.0,0.0) and ends at (1.0,1.0). Such a curve **is** in fact a mapping from interval [0,1] to interval [0,1].

You may want to google what a bezier curve is if you want to understand how to set the coordinates of the control points for a specific curve.

Addendum:

As you clarified, you want to use an existing CAMediaTimingFunction instance to do the mapping from a value to it's transformed value (aka compute the mapping). You can retrieve the coordinates of the control points with getControlPointAtIndex:values: from the instance and use them to compute the mapping. See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) for the math.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I must be missing something obvious here. What I'm after is the ability to pass in a time value between 0 and 1 and get an output value between 0 and 1 that moves along one of the pre-defined curves e.g. kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn. I see I can use the 'functionWithName' method to create a CAMediaTimingFunction instance, but what function do I then use to map my input value to an output value? I'm not interested in creating my own curve, I just want to use kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn.

Comment: @antsyawn - have you figured out how to do this? thanks.

Comment: @SpaceDog - yes, as I commented on the accepted answer, I found the method I was after in the webkit source somewhere. Sorry, this was quite some time ago and I no longer have the code, but it worked great. Good luck :)