# CALayer Presentation nil

Tags: uiview, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I am trying to use a `CABasicAnimation` for the timing function with custom objects (not `UIView`).

I'm trying to implement @CIFilter's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098613/using-camediatimingfunction-to-calculate-value-at-time-t) which is to use the `CALayer`'s presentation layer that is animated to evaluate the timing function.

I'm doing it all in `viewDidAppear`, so a valid view exists, but no matter what I do, the `Presentation` layer is always nil.

Note that I have to add the animation to the view's layer and not the layer I've added to it for it to animate at all. And if I uncomment the lines commented out below I can see that the animation works (but only when animating the root layer). Regardless, the `Presentation` layer is nil.

I've looked at dozen's of tutorials and SO answers, and it seems this should just work, so I suppose I must be doing something stupid.

I am just trying to use the `CoreAnimation` timing functions. I have `UICubicTimingParameters` working, but seems like going the `CA` route offers much more functionality which would be nice.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
        let newView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
        view.addSubview(newView)

        let evaluatorLayer = CALayer()
        evaluatorLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
        evaluatorLayer.borderWidth = 8.0
        evaluatorLayer.borderColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
        evaluatorLayer.timeOffset = 0.3
        evaluatorLayer.isHidden = true
    //  evaluatorLayer.isHidden = false
    
        newView.layer.addSublayer(evaluatorLayer)
    
        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.origin.x")
        basicAnimation.duration = 1.0
        basicAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        basicAnimation.toValue = 100.0
        basicAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        basicAnimation.speed = 0.0
    //  basicAnimation.speed = 0.1
    
        newView.layer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "evaluate")

        if let presentationLayer = newView.layer.presentation() {
            let evaluatedValue = presentationLayer.bounds.origin.x
            print("evaluatedValue: \(evaluatedValue)")
        }
        else {
            print(evaluatorLayer.presentation())
        }
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your code is going to do what you expect, but...

I think the reason `.presentation()` is `nil` is because you haven't given `UIKit` an opportunity to apply the animation.

Try this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    let newView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
    view.addSubview(newView)
    
    let evaluatorLayer = CALayer()
    evaluatorLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    evaluatorLayer.borderWidth = 8.0
    evaluatorLayer.borderColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
    evaluatorLayer.timeOffset = 0.3
    evaluatorLayer.isHidden = true
    //  evaluatorLayer.isHidden = false
    
    newView.layer.addSublayer(evaluatorLayer)
    
    let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.origin.x")
    basicAnimation.duration = 1.0
    basicAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    basicAnimation.toValue = 100.0
    basicAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    basicAnimation.speed = 0.0
    //  basicAnimation.speed = 0.1
    
    newView.layer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "evaluate")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
        if let presentationLayer = newView.layer.presentation() {
            let evaluatedValue = presentationLayer.bounds.origin.x
            print("async evaluatedValue: \(evaluatedValue)")
        }
        else {
            print("async", evaluatorLayer.presentation())
        }
        
    }

    if let presentationLayer = newView.layer.presentation() {
        let evaluatedValue = presentationLayer.bounds.origin.x
        print("immediate evaluatedValue: \(evaluatedValue)")
    }
    else {
        print("immediate", evaluatorLayer.presentation())
    }
    
}
```

My debug output is:

```
immediate nil
async evaluatedValue: 0.0
```

---

**Edit**

I'm still not sure what your goal is, but give this a try...

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    let newView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
    view.addSubview(newView)
    
    let evaluatorLayer = CALayer()
    evaluatorLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    evaluatorLayer.borderWidth = 8.0
    evaluatorLayer.borderColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
    evaluatorLayer.isHidden = true
    //evaluatorLayer.isHidden = false
    
    newView.layer.addSublayer(evaluatorLayer)
    
    let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.origin.x")
    basicAnimation.duration = 1.0
    basicAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    basicAnimation.toValue = 100.0
    basicAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    basicAnimation.speed = 0.0
    //basicAnimation.speed = 1.0

    // set timeOffset on the animation, not on the layer itself
    basicAnimation.timeOffset = 0.3

    // add animation to evaluatorLayer
    evaluatorLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "evaluate")
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
        // get presentation layer of evaluatorLayer
        if let presentationLayer = evaluatorLayer.presentation() {
            let evaluatedValue = presentationLayer.bounds.origin.x
            print("async evaluatedValue: \(evaluatedValue)")
        }
        else {
            print("async", evaluatorLayer.presentation())
        }
        
    }

}
```

In this example, we apply the `.timeOffset` on the animation, not on the layer. And, we add the animation to the `evaluatorLayer`, not to the `newView.layer`.

Output (for my quick test):

```
async evaluatedValue: 30.000001192092896
```

Comment: I was expecting it to work because that is what the answer I linked to says to do and has been upvoted. But, yeah, I get a presentation layer now but `evaluatedValue` is 0.0 even if I set the timeOffset. So something is still not right, but you did answer the question of why presentation is nil, so I accepted it.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. That actually worked - once. But then 0 every time. Hmm, kind of funky to have to use .async for what I want to use it for anyways, so think I'll use what I have now. Darn shame  doesn't expose CATimer functions for use on our own objects.